# PayPal Subscription Integration | Confusion with Capturing Funds

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, paypal, integration

I am currently working on a PayPal Subscription Integration for a client. But I had some issues with PayPal, do I need to capture the funds when the subscription is activated, and do I need to capture the funds every time the next billing cycle is hit? Or do I only need to do 1 of them?

Like, how does this work?

And how do I cancel a subscription when an error occurs when the user is trying to activate his subscription? Should I just cancel it using an API request from my server, or is there a function in the PayPal JS SDK (in the frontend) to cancel it? Since there is a method to `actions.restart()` restart the payment flow, but that is not what I want and doesn't work actually since that gives me an error again for some reason.

It's very confusing, the documentation also isn't helping me on that and PayPal's Community forums are kinda dead.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a [PayPal Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) is approved by the payer, it will become active and bill (capture) automatically. This will be immediate if no start_date is specified.

There is no server-side activation and hence no need for an actions.restart() equivalent.

(An exception to this is if you override the application_context's user_action; this changes the verbiage to indicate you are going to show a review page, and do the activation with an API call)

---

Cancellations are done using API calls, not the JS SDK.

Comment: So does that mean I do not need to capture the funds myself? So to cancel the subscription when an error occurs, I just need to send an API request from my backend to do that. And then have an IPN listener to listen for cancellations to handle them.

The reason I'm asking for confirmation is that when I go to my sandbox business account and go to the subscriptions tab nothing has been added to my account yet and I have to click some buttons on the subscription to actually get the funds.

Comment: What buttons? IPN is a very old service, do not use it. Here are the subscription webhook events you can register for https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late response.

The reason I said IPN instead of webhooks is because I saw many people that issues with webhooks and said that IPN was more stable than webhooks. But I'll use webhooks and see how that goes.

About what I said with buttons, I wasn't clear there.
I have made a short video of what I meant on Streamable, where I'm on a PayPal Sandbox business account where, as you can see, I have to accept the payment before it goes onto my wallet. That's what I meant by, do I need to capture the payment or not? Here is the video: https://streamable.com/e7d8rv

Comment: I have to post this in another comment due to the maximum of characters left. But is there a better way to cancel or better said ABORT the subscription/payment flow when an error occurs, or should I do all my checking before the payment was actually approved by PayPal? Because currently, my client will get a lot of "subscription canceled" messages which isn't very nice. I already do all of my checks before the payment is approved, but if something bad happens I also want it to work after the payment is approved so the customers aren't scammed. Or do you recommend me to leave it like this?

Comment: The payment is unclaimed due to a currency issue, as it's in USD and that account does not have an active USD balance. You can open a USD balance in the money settings. Alternatively, you can change your payment receiving preferences to automatically convert the payment to your primary balance currency (GBP in this case)